# When did it come about that Shmini Atzeret became Simchat Torah?

Tags: simchat-torah, shmini-atzeres

The Torah calls last day of Sukkos Shmini-Atzeres (or techically a separate holiday (PZ"R KS"B)) but at some point in time it became Simchat-Torah (in Israel) or the 2nd day in Chutz L'aretz.
When did this happen ?

Comment: Mossad harav kook have put out a book that I'm sure would address the question (currently only in hebrew) I'm sure it'll be on Otzar Hachachmah
https://www.mosadharavkook.com/shop/ search for תולדות-חג-שמחת-תורה

Comment: Are you asking why we finish the Torah on simchat Torah?

Answer (score -2):

I think the question should be : when Shmini Atzeres became ALSO simchat Torah.It is Ezra tha decided to read the all Torah not anymore in 3 years but in one year.He decided to make it a simh'a and choose Shmini Atzeres. Why ? I have yo look bn